# Unindent does not match any outer indentation level?

Tags: python

I have the following python code.

```
import sys

ins = open( sys.argv[1], "r" )
array = []
for line in ins:
    s = line.split()
    array.append( s[0] ) # <-- Error here 
print array

ins.close()
```

The python interpreter complains

```
  File "sort.py", line 7
    array.append( s[0] )
                       ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Why so? And how to correct this error?

Comment: [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#pet-peeves) recommends that you don't write function arguments like `foo( x, y )`.

Comment: Run your script with `python -tt`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing tabs and spaces (happens sometimes :). Use one or the other.

I looked at your source:

```
    s = line.split()  # there's a tab at the start of the line
    array.append( s[0] )  # spaces at the start of the line
```

---

Aside: As just a friendly suggestion, consider using `with` to open your file. The advantage is that the file will be automatically closed for you (no `close()` needed) when you are done or an exception is encountered.

```
array = []
with open( sys.argv[1], "r" ) as ins:  # "r" really not needed, it's the default.
   for line in ins:
      s = line.split()
      # etc...
```

Answer (score 3):

run your code with `python -tt sort.py`.

It'll show you whether you've mixed tabs and spaces or not.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your indentation is consistent using either spaces or tabs and not a mix of the two.